# Recursive function to list every element from cell arrays in Matlab

Tags: matlab, recursion, combinations

I am trying to get all possible combinations of elements from an array of vectors. For example, say, I have a cell array

```
C = {[1 2 3 4 5], [6:13], [14 15]}
```

then the output should be something like

```
out = {[1 6 14], [1 6 15], [1 7 14], [1 7 15],....,[5 13 15]}
```

I tried to use a recursive function to implement this, but the code below doesn't seem to work. How can I obtain the list of all these combinations?

```matlab
function [out,i] = permuteTest2(a,i,N,l,out)
    if nargin == 0
        a={[1 2],[4 5],[7 8]};
        N = length(a);
        i = 1;
        out = [];
    end
    if i == N
        out = [out, a{i}(l)];
        return;
    else
        for k=i:N
            L = length(a{k});
            for l=1:L
                out =[out a{k}(l)];
                [out,i] =permuteTest2(a, i+1, N,l,out);
            end
        end
    end
```

Comment: Please also [edit] the post on why you want to do this. As I said: for small problems this is trivial, whereas for slightly larger problems this quickly becomes impossible. For only 30 cells with 2 numbers each you'd need 2 full weeks of processing of processing, when a single permutation takes only a millisecond! Thus, why do you need *all* permutations? This smells of an optimisation problem, for which (much much) better solutions than brute forcing a grid search exist, exactly because calculating all possibilities takes infeasibly long.

Comment: You could select a random permutation as follows: `for ii = 1:length(C); out(ii) = C{ii}(randi(numel(C{ii})));end`, i.e. for each element in `C`, pick a random index and store the number on that index.

Comment: Your title asks for "every element" but your question asks for "**a** possible combination", but then you've shown an example of **all** combinations... which is it? Do you just want a random element from your example `out`, or do you want the complete set of permutations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a cell array `C` with N vectors in it. To get all combinations of one element from each vector, you need to combine each element from the first vector with all combinations of the remaining vectors:

```matlab
function combs = all_combinations(C)
   a = C{1};
   b = all_combinations(C(2:end));
   % ... get all the combinations of a and b here
```

If `C` has only one element, then all combinations is just that element (let's convert it to a cell array with one number in each cell, to match the expected output format):

```matlab
function combs = all_combinations(C)
   a = C{1};
   if numel(C) == 1
      combs = num2cell(a);
      return;
   end
   b = all_combinations(C(2:end));
   % ... get all the combinations of a and b here
```

This takes care of the recursive part. Now all we need to do is find all combinations of the two sets `a` and `b`:

```matlab
function combs = all_combinations(C)
   a = C{1};
   if numel(C) == 1
      combs = num2cell(a);
      return;
   end
   b = all_combinations(C(2:end));
   combs = cell(numel(a), numel(b));
   for ii = 1:numel(a)
      for jj = 1:numel(b)
         combs{ii, jj} = [a(ii), b{jj}];
      end
   end
   combs = combs(:);
```

To understand the answer above, it is important to track which elements are cell arrays and which are not, and how we index cell arrays (`{}` to extract an element from the array, `()` to index parts of the cell array, creating a new cell array).

I also used `numel` everywhere instead of `length`. `numel` is more efficient, and allows the code above to work equally well if instead of vectors you input arrays with more than one dimension.

A more robust function would test the input `C` to be a cell array with at least one element, and it would test each of the elements of this cell array to be a numeric array (or vector).